# Analytics: Advanced Link Tracking

Tags: javascript, analytics, tracking, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to trigger a variable only when links within a specific Div are clicked. I cant tag every single link inside the div, so I'm trying to find an alternative. I was thinking a function to check for the parent div would work.

Comment: What are you using? GA, Doubleclick, a custom solution? If custom, what libraries (if any) are you using?

Comment: Using adobe analytics, currently leveraging a plugin called setupLinkTracking. With this plugin we get what page they are coming from, the link name, and position. The problem is that our links are not tagged properly to be able to capture the position using the plugin, so I am trying to setup a variable for the same purpose just for the time between now and when we are able to update all the links.

Comment: if you are using an existing framework like jQuery and the div has something unique like an id or a unique class name, you could use jQuery to attach a click handler to all the links in the div

Comment: example `$('$divID').on('click','a',function(e) { /* pop omn code here using $(this) to get values */ });`

Comment: Check out forum! The forum is a great place to bounce ideas off other users and get live feedback.you Might find solution here  http://adobe.ly/1juTbTO